# Distribution ad hoc over the air with iOS 7

Tags: ios7, ad-hoc-distribution, ota

The method that I used with iOS6 does not work now

When I try to download the app by iOS7 device i get alert view with text "cannot connect to www....", while with iOS6 device I can download and install app.

why?

Comment: Same Issue.  If I find something I will post as an answer but at the moment I am not having much luck finding an answer.  Worked fine on iOS6, pushed app to server with valid provisioning profile and it's a server we have used in the past.  Most recent build of the app and this started happening.

Comment: I solved my problem by shifting it to a https server. @Biga is correct.

Answer (score 3):

iOS 7 requires the manifest file to be on HTTPS (with a trusted certificate).
I've found a great suggestion on the Internet - put the manifest into Dropbox. Dropbox gives out public files via https, and it has trusted certificate. It works for me.